# Ability to reorder percentile tags in profile

Tags: feature-request, jobs

The percentile tags that appear in the Careers 2.0 user profile are helpful to communicate the specialtes. To make them even more useful, it would be great to be able to reorder them to cover the following use cases:

- Related tags are displayed together
- Tags that the user considers more relevant are displayed first.

As an example, in my profile I had `python`, `gtk` and `pygtk`. After that, `csv` was added between `python` and `gtk`. That's completely fine, but I'd prefer to move `csv` to the end since that tag isn't as relevant in my opinion as `gtk` and `pygtk`.